# The default function argument does not work

Tags: javascript, function, default-arguments

There is a function that has default argument values

```js
const range = (start = 0, stop, step = 1) => {
  console.log('start', start)
  console.log('stop', stop)
  console.log('step', step)
}

range(4)
```

Please explain why the console displays

```js
start 4
stop undefined
step 1
```

Although in my opinion it should come out

```js
start 0
stop 4
step 1
```

since I passed a default value for the start argument. How can this behavior be corrected? Thanks

Comment: _"Although in my opinion it should come out"_ - why? You only passed in the first argument. --- If you don't want to care about the param order, use an object.

Comment: argument order matters. Javascript won't automatically assign the argument value to a parameter for which you didn't provide a default value. Change `range(4)` to `range(undefined, 4, undefined)`

Comment: `range(undefined,4)` will do

Comment: alternatively, use a single object as the argument ... `const range = ({start = 0, stop, step = 1}) => {` and `range({stop:4})`

Comment: The default value you declare in arguments works only if the value of that argument is falsy.

Comment: @AdilBimzagh not falsy. Only undefined. `fn = (a = 'hello') => a; fn(null); fn(false); // null and false`

Comment: @AdilBimzagh _"...only if the value of that argument is falsy"_ - no. if the value is  `undefined`

Comment: Trust the MDN documentation over your gut.

Comment: Ooops, You're right guys!

Answer (score 2):

pass the first argument as undefined - since arguments to functions are "positional", i.e first argument gets the first value in the call, second gets second etc

If you pass `undefined` as an argument, the "default value" (if present) is assigned

```js
const range = (start = 0, stop, step = 1) => {
  console.log('start', start)
  console.log('stop', stop)
  console.log('step', step)
}

range(undefined, 4)
```

Or use a single object as the argument, with the properties start, stop step

Makes calling it self documented too

```js
const range = ({start = 0, stop, step = 1}) => {
  console.log('start', start)
  console.log('stop', stop)
  console.log('step', step)
}

range({stop:4})
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you're passing no value for the second argument. Thus it remains the implicit `undefined`.

If you want something that behaves like you'd expect there, you'll need

```js
function range(start = undefined, stop = undefined, step = 1) {
  if (stop === undefined && start !== undefined) {
    stop = start;
    start = 0;
  }
  console.log("start", start);
  console.log("stop", stop);
  console.log("step", step);
}

range(4);
```

instead.

Comment: `start = undefined, stop = undefined` - undefined default values are redundant, are they not?

Comment: Yes, but they signal to the reader that the arguments are thought to be optional.

Comment: but, they aren't optional :p not both - oh, right .. hmmm ... it's not obvious though :p

Answer (score 1):

The `4` argument you're passing is for the `start` parameter. Argument and parameter positions in JavaScript are purely ordered, the decision of where to assign that `4` isn't based on the total number of arguments passed, purely *where* the argument was passed. Since it was in the first position, it's assigned to the first parameter, `start`.

If you wanted your result, you'd pass `undefined` for `start`:

```
range(undefined, 4)
```

Live Example:

```js
const range = (start = 0, stop, step = 1) => {
  console.log('start', start)
  console.log('stop', stop)
  console.log('step', step)
}

range(undefined, 4)
```

You could handle assigning the values based on the number of arguments received instead, though that probably wouldn't be ideal (it would be uncommon, so possibly surprising). But you *could* do it, by accepting a rest parameter and work from there... I don't recommend it.

Another approach is to accept an options object:

```
const range = ({start = 0, stop, step = 1}) => {
    if (typeof stop === "undefined") {
        throw new Error(`The 'stop' option is required`);
    }
    console.log(`start = ${start}, stop = ${stop}, step = ${step}`);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const range = ({start = 0, stop, step = 1}) => {
    if (typeof stop === "undefined") {
        throw new Error(`The 'stop' option is required`);
    }
    console.log(`start = ${start}, stop = ${stop}, step = ${step}`);
}

range({stop: 4});
range({start: 1, stop: 5});
range({start: 1, stop: 5, step: 2});
```